# How to clear previous BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, invoke, begininvoke

How to clear previous not already executed BeginInvoke on a ui control before adding a new begin invoke.

In my WinForm application I've a status bar that I update frequently from a background process, but if I use Invoke I slow down background process performance, so I want to use begin invoke, but I want that status is synchronized with the last BeginInvoke. So when I call a new BeginInvoke I want to clear previous not already executed BeginInvoke.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: How about simply making the method you invoke using BeginInvoke imdepotent, so that even if you call it twice, that won't matter, it will still update to the right value (twice)?

Comment: Nop, there is no way to do what you are asking for, there might be workarounds but nothing out-of-the-box

Comment: ...or it's a different problem than you think.  We would have to see the code that produces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you call BeginInvoke so often that your UI thread does not event manage to dequeue the invocation, than you should consider either lowering the frequency of calling BeginInvoke, or changing the method of updating the UI (timer?). Also agreed with Lasse's comment.

Comment: Thank you, in my project there are more more background process that call the UI process, it is not only the status bar update. So happens that the invoke on UI process are too much and UI starts to show old values. I'm searching something to thash old invoke or to see the invoke queue on UI process.